# cudaMemset failed to set all values to 0

Tags: cuda

I am trying to debug my cuda code and I am confused about how to get `cudaMemset` to work properly. Below is the bugged part.

```
unsigned int * h_histogram;
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocHost((void **)&h_histogram,sizeof(unsigned int)*numBins));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(h_histogram, 0, numBins));
std::cout << "Num Bins = " << numBins << std::endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i < numBins; ++i)
{
printf("%u %u %u\n", i, h_histogram[i]);}
```

In this code, `numBins = 1024`. However, when I printed it out, only the first 256 values of the array h_histogram is set to 0, the rest is set to a bunch of random numbers. Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thrid parameter of `cudaMemset` ist the size in bytes, that shoulb be set with the destinated value. You input only the count of elements.
You have to change it to this, like you did with `cudaMallocHost` right before.

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(h_histogram, 0, numBins*sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Comment: Great, that works. Do you have any idea why the developer said that the third parameter should be size_t? Like in this link http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/cuda/doc/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_ge07c97b96efd09abaeb3ca3b5f8da4ee.html

Comment: @beginner: `size_t` is not "size of type" but "size type" -- a type designed to hold the size of something. In this case, that "something" is number of bytes.